# Is it possible to alter the layout of a terminal in a VSC extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to add a button next to the terminal dropdown but can't see a way in the API to do this

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview):

> [...] However, we also impose [restrictions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#restrictions) upon extensions to ensure the stability and performance of VS Code. For example, extensions cannot access the DOM of VS Code UI.

Therefore I think it is not possible to add a button next to the terminal.